# can't find external reference within capacitor

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, capacitor

I'm starting with es6 and capacitorjs.

I need to build a google auth for an app.

I followed this instructions here https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth.

Tried too many different things, looks like there is an issue about not serving the node_modules folder in my webserver, but I really can't figure out what is wrong.

I'm attaching an image which represents my directory structure:

[image]

The index.js file is declared in index.html file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{your client id here}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>my title</h1>

</body>

<script src="capacitor.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
<script >
        //this is working properly, but capacitor.js is declared here
        console.log('element is loaded...')
        Capacitor.Plugins.Storage.set({key:'test', value:'val'});
        Capacitor.Plugins.Storage.get({ key: 'test' }).then(function(result) {
            document.querySelector('h1').innerText = 'chave:' + result.value;
        });

</script>

</html>
```

the index.js file goes below:

```
import "../@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth";
import { Plugins } from '../@capacitor/core';
Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();
```

My console output:
[image]

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.6",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.6",
    "@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth": "^2.1.3",
    "serve": "^11.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "yarn serve www"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: any idea? it should be a simple issue

Comment: Do do get any errors after building the project?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Just needed to add a code transpiler.

In my case, i added parceljs.

```
yarn global add parcel-bundler
```

Later, i made a new folder to keep my source code.

```
mkdir frontend
```

Finally, added a new script called watch in my package.json file

```
"scripts": {
"watch": "parcel watch frontend/*.html --out-dir www"
}
```